# Rotate Screen - imageview android

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, imageview, screen

When I turn my phone screen is activated onSaveInstanceState method (Bundle bundle), I capture the screen data and I store in onSaveInstanceState Bundle. At the end of the screen rotation is enabled onRestoreInstanceState method (Bundle bundle), I capture the bundle data using, for example: bundle.getString (key).

However, when I use ImageView I capture the image, convert to bitmap and then to string, I store and retrieve when to make aa conversion, it is not made and is the default image.

I suspect that should store the image String so choose it from the gallery. What do you think?

Some other tutorials say that this is not feasible and should store in SD and then recover it in the onCreate method.